# Disable HTML Emails in composer

Tags: email, html, motoblur

how do I disable the default sending of emails in html format? 
I would like to compose emails in the text format but I can't find a way to do that. Ideally, this should be the default behaviour with an option to enable html when needed.

Using Android 2.1, Motorola Defy, Standard Email app (might be some Motoblur changes made, I don't know).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using K-9 Mail. I am relatively certain, that making text encoding the default behaviour for the stock Android Email app is not possible.

For this reason and others I am using now K-9 Mail. It has down sides but it solves this problem.