# How to compose plain text email

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable HTML Emails in composer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/disable-html-emails-in-composer)

I'm baffled - my Samsung Galaxy Note running Android Ice Cream Sandwich ICS 4.0.4 has a default email client - which is rather neat.

One thing that baffles me - how to make it send email in plain text form only - HTML email is evil and it seems to be composing HTML by default.

I tried googling, but with so many generic terms - it's hard to find proper keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not available in the app settings, the functionality most likely simply isn't there. There are other clients you can use if it's important to you. If you want some tips for alternative apps, I suggest you look at [The Best Alternative Android Apps to Manage All Your Email](http://www.tested.com/news/feature/3110-the-best-alternative-android-apps-to-manage-all-your-email/), or Google for a similar article.